# Harry Potter fanfic about Harry and Hermione dying and then going back in time to their first year selves

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

There was this Harry Potter fanfic I read on Aldiko book reader. It was about Harry and Hermione dying and then going back in time to their first year selves. However Hermione doesn't remember right away! Harry ends up with the Dursley's. He goes to Hogwarts and is kind of a genius there because he already knows all the things that are being taught.

In 4th year Hermione and Harry get married. They got married really young but they've known each other since the past life. They also get to be professors at Hogwarts regardless of their age. Another thing in that story they befriend Draco instead of Ron because Ron and Ginny most likely betrayed them in their past life.

Comment: Can you elaborate on some of the canon divergences? Do they track down the horcruxes early? Steal the Philosopher's Stone before Voldemort can go after it? Avoid changes as much as possible to preserve their future knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for ''the time meddlers'' by witowsmp on fanfiction.net. It's been a while since I've read it so I'm not certain on the getting married part, but for the rest it sounds very similar.

> It was about Harry and Hermione dying and then going back in time to their first year selves.
>
> > ''While researching some books she had taken from grimmauld place while they were living there, Hermione came across a difficult potion that allowed you to send your mind and soul back in your body a specific amount of birthdays... Once it's ingested, the traveler would have one hour to activate it. The only way to activate it would be to die.
>
> However Hermione doesn't remember right away!
>
> > At the stroke of midnight, a hermione granger woke up at hogwarts, but it wasn't the one who went to sleep. Staring at the dark ceiling, the eighteen-year-old woman in a twelve-year-old body gasped as she felt information from the past nineteen days begin pouring into her head.

now that I've skimmed the story I'm starting to doubt it's what you're looking for, I can't find any references to the other points like them being friends with draco or getting married.